# Hide columns under condition when exporting csv

Tags: magento-1.9, php, xml, csv, export

Fyi, I did read from another similar post where I came to a good solution (Setting is system true will prevent it from getting exported).

However, my problem is I would like to have two type of csv export where the first type will export all columns. The second type will only export certain column. I cant set `is_system` true as this will hide the columns from both types of export function. Is there any way to set condition in the controller where it can set `is_system` true to the grid or any alternative way?

Beforehand, let me thank you in advance.

```
   public function example()
    {
        $fileName   = 'example.csv';
        $content    = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('example/example_grid')
            ->getCsv();

        $this->_sendUploadResponse($fileName, $content);
    }
```

//Grid

```
$this->addColumn('detail', array(
    'header'    => Mage::helper('example')->__('Detail'),
    'align'     => 'left',
    'renderer'  => 'example/example'
));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create a new grid file with wanted columns only and then call the grid from controller.

Like this:

**In your main Grid.php**

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
{

    .......................
    ...............
    other stuff
    .................

    $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('sales')->__('CSV'));
    $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsvWithoutSomeColumn', Mage::helper('sales')->__('CSV Without some column'));

    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}
```

**In your controller:**

```
/**
 * Export order grid to CSV format
 */
public function exportCsvAction()
{
    $fileName   = 'your_file_name.csv';
    $grid       = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('module/path_to_grid');
    //$grid       = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/sales_order_grid');
    $this->_prepareDownloadResponse($fileName, $grid->getCsvFile());
}


/**
 * Export order grid to CSV format
 */
public function exportCsvWithoutSomeColumnAction()
{
    $fileName   = 'your_file_name_without_column.csv';
    $grid       = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('module/path_to_gridwithoutsomecolumn');
    $this->_prepareDownloadResponse($fileName, $grid->getCsvFile());
}
```

**Now, create another grid, copy `_prepareCollection()` function from your main grid and paste in here**

```
<?php
//new grid extends your original gri
class NameSpace_ModuleName_Block_Adminhtml_Path_To_Gridwithoutsomecolumn extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
     public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('your_grid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('your_id');
        $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
      //only allowed column
    }
}
```

Now, remove unwanted column and then save.

This should work.